# Why is the force on a smooth massless pulley the sum of the tensions on both ends and not the wieght of the system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

If we have a smooth and frictionless pulley with two different masses attached at the ends of the rope (meaning they will accelerate) and the pulley is attached to the roof by a string, why cant we consider everything as one closed system and calculate the wieght of the that system to find the tension on the string attaching the pulley to the roof. After thinking for some time I feel that somehow allowing the masses to accelerate in one direction is relieving some of the force on the pulley. But why? Why can't we consider it a single system and find its wieght?

Comment: The answer is that the centre of mass of the single system is accelerating downwards, so the tension in the rope to the roof is less than the combined weight of the single system.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent i see.  thanks.